# Check each item of one array for matches in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, match

I am currently trying to program a word game where the player types the words he/she finds into a text box and hits submit. After hitting submit, that word is stored in an array that I can do something with in Javascript, and the textbox is cleared so that they can enter another word. I think I can figure those parts out eventually (I am new to HTML and JavaScript), but I have no idea how to do what I want to do next. I need to check each of the words that the player found against an array of verified words. I have found some codes on here that will search for whether a single word matches any strings an array, but how would I write a code that checks all of the words the player finds against a dictionary/verified array?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over every element in your user array and use IndexOf to see if it exists in your verified array. IndexOf will return -1 if it was not found.

```
for (var i = 0; i < userArray.length ; i++) 
    if(verifiedWordArray.indexOf(userArray[i]) == -1)
        return false;     
return true;
```

If you have to match specific position, this would do the trick assuming they are both of the same length.

```
for (var i = 0; i < userArray.length ; i++) 
    if(userArray[i] != verifiedWordArray[i])
        return false;     
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

pseudo code:

```
ans = true // assume the user is right
for (each of the words in user input array){
    if(current word is not in the predefined array){ // use .indexOf()
        ans = false
        break; //stop loop
    }
}
```

Once this loop is done `ans` will be true or false according to the user's input.

Answer (score 0):

If you do it on the client side, you can store your word's dictionary in an array, for instance `array= ["one","two", "three","word"]`, and then check if the user's word `word` against your dictionary with this `array.indexOf('word') > -1`

Answer (score 0):

```
function getIntersect(arr1, arr2) {
    var r = [], o = {}, l = arr2.length, i, v;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        o[arr2[i]] = true;
    }
    l = arr1.length;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        v = arr1[i];
        if (v in o) {
            r.push(v);
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

From: http://www.falsepositives.com/index.php/2009/12/01/javascript-function-to-get-the-intersect-of-2-arrays/